# iOS authentication with Twitter's Digits framework

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, twitter-digits

I have an iOS app that allows user to authenticate with their facebook or twitter account. Apple rejected my because of the following:

> We noticed that your app uses a Facebook and Twitter login for
>       authentication purposes but does not include account-based features 
>       offered by that site, which does not comply with the App Store Review 
>       Guidelines.
>
> In order to use Facebook and Twitter for authentication, your app must 
>       include significant account-specific functionality from Facebook and 
>       Twitter. For example, your app should include sufficient account-based 
>       features from Facebook and Twitter other than pulling profile 
>       information or sharing on the user’s page.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please revise your app to implement your own authentication mechanism,
>   or incorporate significant account-specific functionality from
>   Facebook and Twitter.
>
> If your app does include additional account-specific features from
>   Facebook and Twitter, please provide us with details on where we can
>   locate these features in your app.

I'm thinking about adding twitter's digits framework so that users can authenticate with their phone number if they'd like. Does anyone know if that would qualify, or will I need to roll my own authentication?

The periscope app has two login options: Twitter account and phone number via Digits. But it's possible they meet with apple's guidelines because they have more social features in their app.

Comment: What Apple is stating is something about the app experience & functionality from the user perspective. They wouldn't like you to use it unless e.g. for twitter there was Twitter-related activity, for Facebook you could tell the user whose friends already have the app, etc. Something merely technical won't do, since the reviewer wants your app to have more twitter/facebook interaction.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to paste the next part of their response. I've edited my question to include it.

I take their "Next Steps" section to mean that I have 2 options, I could add more social features or add my own authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Digits yet? We once got rejected by Apple for only having a Facebook login, so we added an anonymous login to get past review. We are currently considering doing a Facebook and Digits approach and removing anonymous for new accounts, so I, too, am curious if it would be allowed.

Comment: I'm not sure. I ended up building username/password signup/login. I just wanted to pass review and wanted to minimize risk. Maybe one day I'll take the risk with a new version of my app and replace un/pw with digits.